# viewing multiple segments in UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

i have the following 6 segments in my UISegmentedControl

1)Objective
2)Concept
3)How-to-Do
4)Note
5)Simulation
6)CYU

when i launch my app i get to see only 3 segments while the other 3 remain hidden due to the simulators frame,how can i display all the 6 segments? how to toggle across the other segments? sorry for the noob question,i couldnt find any solution to this anywhere

Comment: Is the control frame larger than the screen size ? If so, did you try to use a scrollView, is it an option ?

Comment: Its better u create a custom segmented control.... or use another control for that matter

Comment: @A-Live yes i tried scroll view but to no avail,it does not help me out,can i put two arrows and scroll across my segments?

Comment: Putting the UISegmentControl in a UIScrollView will be the my suggestion.

Comment: Of course you can, add the icons to the left and right segments, make their frame smaller than center segments frame, process arrows and central segments separately changing displayed text or doing the selection stuff. It's not animated though.

Comment: @A-Live where can i find code for that online?

Comment: You might try to find it at http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls or you can use `Three20` Tab controls (see TTCatalog demo app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO; //disable horizontal scroll
scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO; //disable vertical scroll

NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Objective", @"Concept", @"How-to-Do",@"Note",@"Simulation",@"CYU", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray]; //provide array of segment names
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 50);//change accordingly
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1; //by default selected index

[scroll addSubview:segmentedControl]; // add segment 
 scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(segmentedControl.frame.size.width, segmentedControl.frame.size.height+10); //change accordingly
[segmentedControl release]; 
[self.view addSubview:scroll]; //add scroll view
```